# How do I add permissions to an OU using C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to give Access Permission on OU of Active Directory. I have done some part as below, which removes all access of OU. The code is as below:

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Test OU,DC=test,DC=com"); 
DirectorySearcher dsFindOUs = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry); 
 
dsFindOUs.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)"; 
dsFindOUs.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree; 
SearchResult oResults = dsFindOUs.FindOne(); 
DirectoryEntry myOU = oResults.GetDirectoryEntry(); 
 
System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("YourDomain", "YourUserName").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)); 
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule newRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.deny); 
myOU.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule(newRule); myOU.Commitchanges();
```

Now the problem is if I remove all the permission from AD OU then how I can give the permission again(revert the permissions again). I tried with System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow for newRule. But as there is no permission for the OU it throws exception on :

```
SearchResult oResults = dsFindOUs.FindOne(); 
DirectoryEntry myOU = oResults.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

How can I give rights again to perticualr OU again in C#.

#### Update:

```
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny);
```

But the problem is I have already removed all the Generic Rights, and when I try to search the OU again it won't find it again. So I can't apply the suggested logic again.
You can try it out:).
Give me some way, how I can access the OU again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this line:

```
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule newRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny);
```

with this:

```
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule newRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
```

- change the "Deny" to "Allow".

P.S. : Please format the code lines in your question to appear as code.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the Quick answer, but the problem is when I remove all the rights(using GenericAll),and when I use search the OU again it thows exception, as OU not found. So I can't use above code.

Comment: Above suggested change will not work as we have removed all rights. This code will fail when we Search for the OU, and we never Allow the Generic All Permissions to the OU. Please conform.